# Suppressing xterm in Qt app

Tags: qt

Every time I run Qt app on my Red Hat system additional terminal window pop up.  For example I tried this project http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html. There is no CONFIG += console string in .pro file, I tried to add CONFIG -= console, but this doesn't help. On my Ubuntu system everything is fine. Only difference is that on Ubuntu I compile projects with qmake, on Red Hat - with qmake4. So how can I suppress this terminal window?

Comment: Do you have `Run in Terminal` in configuration properties ?

Comment: How can I check this? You mean configurations of Qt or configuration of my linux system for executable files?

Comment: Go to the *Projects* area, then you should see two sub-tab (`Build` and `Run`) under you kit tab. Click `Run`. The `Run in Terminal` option is located in the *Run* area.

Comment: I'm trying to run compiled QT application. I don't have Qt Creator on my Red Hat system and I don't have ability to install it, there are only QtConfiguration with 'tabs': Apperance, Fonts, Interface, Printer, Phonon - there are no terminal options. Basically I create all my Qt files on Ubuntu and then have to compile them on Red Hat. On Ubuntu, "Run in Terminal option" in QtCreator is set to disable.